# How to construct predicate for HashMap::retain when the value is a tuple?

Tags: scala

I have a Map that has a type as:

```
val m: HashMap[Double, (Double, Long)]
```

When I run the retain method:

```
m.retain(p => true)
```

It complains `Type mismatch. Expected: (Double, (Double, Long)) => Boolean, actual: Double => Boolean`

Then I tried to add the type signature to the parameter:

```
m.retain(p: (Double, (Double, Long)) => true)
```

It then complains `Type mismatch. Expected: (Double, (Double, Long)) => Boolean, actual: (Double, (Double, Long)) => Boolean`, which does not make sense to me because they are the same.

I also tried:

```
m.retain((k,(v,t))=>true)
```

Still giving a Type mismatch error.

I thought it could be error with checker so I tried running compiler then gives me another different error: `identifier expected but 'true' found`

How can I do retain in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`scala.collection.mutable.MapLike.retain` parameter `p` is a function that takes two arguments: `key` and `value` (it's not a function that takes a `tuple` with `key` and `value`)

You need to write it like this:

```
m.retain((k, v) => true)
```

Or like this:

```
m.retain({
  case (k, v) => true
})
```

Or like this:

```
m.retain({
  case (k, (v1, v2)) => true
})
```

Comment: The last one is what I was expecting... So there is an implicit conversion from PartialFunction to lambda? Where can I find any reference to that?

Comment: You can use PartialFunction with pattern matching for implementing both functions (a function that takes multiple arguments and a function that takes a tuple).

Comment: Ya so PartialFunction case clause destructs the nested tuple? The regular function cannot seem to do that like `m.retain((k,(v,t))=>true)` gives error...

Comment: I wrote another answer for this

Comment: `m.retain((k,(v,t))=>true)` gives error because lambda can't extract tuple (v, t) from map value. Lets wait for `dotty` http://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/auto-parameter-tupling.html

Answer (score 1):

You have the following functions:

```
//function that takes a function that takes multiple arguments
def test1(f: (Int, Int) => Boolean): Boolean = f(0, 0)
//function that takes a function that takes a tuple
def test2(f: ((Int, Int)) => Boolean): Boolean = f((0, 0))
```

When you use PartialFunction and write

```
test1({
  case (v1, v2) => true
})
```

it equals to

```
test1((arg1, arg2) => (arg1, arg2) match {
  case (v1, v2) => true
})
```

But when you use PartialFunction and write

```
test2({
  case (v1, v2) => true
})
```

it equals to

```
test2(tuple => tuple match {
  case (v1, v2) => true
})
```

Both cases seem the same, but they work differently. In the case of multiple arguments, `match` process the tuple of arguments. In the case of a single tuple argument, `match` process this tuple.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!